How to print the result from a loop in one line on the console in Javascript
I'm trying to print out the result from a loop onto the console but it keeps printing on a new line instead of printing everything on the same line.
This is the output I'm expecting:
...17°C in 1 days ... 21°C in 2 days ... 21°C in 3 days

But this is the output I keep getting:
... 17°C in 1 days

... 21°C in 2 days

... 23°C in 3 days

I've tried most of the answers I found but they are not working.


const arr =[17, 21, 23];

function printForcast(arr) {  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let days = i;

    if(i <= days){
      days +=1;
    }

    console.log(`... ${arr[i]}°C in ${days} days`); 
  }
  return arr;
}

printForcast(arr);
<!DOCTYPE html>




You can append the data you want to print as a string and then print it after the loop.

Not related to the question, but let days = i followed by if (i <= days) days += 1 can be simplified to const days = i + 1 since i <= days is always true.

Does this answer your question? javascript use console.log without moving to new line

"I've tried most of the answers I found but they are not working" should be true of every question asked on Stack Overflow and is not necessary to say explicitly.  In fact, it is expected that everyone makes that preliminary effort before asking a question.

In case you are looking for a node.js solution: Node.js: printing to console without a trailing newline?

Since console.log() will always output a newline, you'll need to append (+=) your output to a string, and then log that after the loop:


const arr =[17, 21, 23];

function printForcast(arr) {
  
  let output = '';
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let days = i;

   if(i <= days){
      days +=1;
   }
   output += `... ${arr[i]}°C in ${days} days`; 
 }
 
  console.log(output);
}

printForcast(arr);




Thanks a lot. I've spent almost two hours looking for answers. I'm new to javaScript so a lot of things keep confusing me.

Can you please explain why using only = doesn't work but it has to be +=

I;ve added a link to some details. You first make an empty string (output = '') then you append (+=) another string. (IT's the same as output = ouput + 'new-part')

Just collect the log items in an array and print at once in the end:


const arr =[17, 21, 23];
const log = [];
function printForcast(arr) {
  
  //let currentTemp = temperatures[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let days = i;

   if(i <= days){
    days +=1;
    // console.log (days);
   }
    log.push(`... ${arr[i]}°C in ${days} days`); 
 }
  console.log(log.join(', '));
  return arr;
}

printForcast(arr);
<!DOCTYPE html>




I think this simple snippet would work


const arr = [17, 21, 23];
function printForcast(arr) {
      let message = '';
      arr.forEach((item,index) => {
        const current = `... ${item}°C in ${index + 1} days `;
        message +=  current;
      });
      console.log(message.trimEnd()); 
      // trimEnd to avoid space on the last one 
}
printForcast(arr);



Hope this helps :)
